# RxJs catch doesn't work after subscribe on the same observer

Tags: rxjs

I'm running into this unexplainable behavior with RxJS and I can't seem to understand why. I have the following piece of code.

```
console.clear();
var rx = Rx.Observable;

var o = rx.throw(['error']);
var o2 = o.catch(x => rx.of(5));
// o.subscribe(x => console.log("1" + x));
o2.subscribe(x => console.log("2:" + x));
```

JsBin link: https://jsbin.com/hikopob/edit?html,js,console

When I run the above code, it prints 2:5 which is what I would expect. However, if I un-comment the commented line, I see following in the console:

> "error"
>
> "Uncaught error (line 10)"

I don't see 2:5 printed in console anymore. What I don't understand is that, how is the subscribe() handler is affecting the next one? What happened to my catch() handler? Why is o2.subscribe() completely ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you uncomment the `o.subscribe`, `o` emits an error notification, for which you have no handler (you only set the `onNext` handler), so that is why you get the `Uncaught error (line 10)` message. So the program exits before even reaching `o2.subscribe(x => console.log("2:" + x));`

If you try this, you will see the difference :

```
console.clear();
var rx = Rx.Observable;

var o = rx.throw(['error']);
var o2 = o.catch(x => rx.of(5));
o.subscribe(x => console.log("1" + x), x => console.log("error:" + x));
o2.subscribe(x => console.log("2:" + x));
```

Comment: Thanks. That answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = rx.throw(['error']);
o.subscribe(x => console.log("1" + x));
```

`o` is the observable you are subscribing to with its sequence of rxjs functions. `o` itself *does not have a catch* when you subscribe to it.

```
var o2 = o.catch(x => rx.of(5));
```

Here you have added a catch and assigned the new observable to `o2`.

So only `o2` has the `catch()` function and not `o`.

> What I don't understand is that, how is the subscribe() handler is affecting the next one?

It is not. The issue is as explained, `o` observable does not have catch() at the time of subscribing.